# Is CLGeocoder supported on iOS 4.2?

Tags: ios

When I look at apple docs, I get a bit confused.

- On one hand they have statements indicating that CLGeocoder can be used from ***iOS 5 onwards***.
- On the other hand they have statements like: "For applications running on ***iOS 4.1 and earlier***, you must perform reverse-geocoding requests using the MKReverseGeocoder class"
- Then what about the 4.2 onwards range? Can it support CLGeocoder or not?

Does anyone have an answer via their first hand experience with an iPhone with 4.1 < version < 5.0 installed where they figured out if CLGeocoder will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I call 
[[CLGeocoder class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:)]

This always returns false on devices below 5.0

I'm still trying to figure out why as the documentation states its supported 4.1 onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the info about actual usage on the device and its results. Yeah the docs are what must be out of whack then :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is quote from the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1):

> In iOS, you can use either the CLGeocoder or MKReverseGeocoder class
>   to handle reverse-geocoding requests. The CLGeocoder is the preferred
>   class to use and is available in iOS 5.0 and later. However, if your
>   application must run on earlier versions of iOS, you can use the
>   MKReverseGeocoder class.

MKReveresGeocoder is still there in 5.0, but is deprecated. That is, you could still use it to simplify support for multiple iOS versions in your code.

Comment: Thanks, my question is based off of that guide actually. I'm asking if there is a chance that CLGeocoder may be present in sdks between 4.1 & 5.0, please have a look at my question more closely and let me know.

Comment: I don't know for sure. But all documentation (both the Location Awareness guide, and the CLGeocode class reference) show in multiple places that it is only available from 5.0 onwards. There is only one spot where the ambiguous statement is made that you quote. But why do you care?

Comment: I want to work with only CLGeocoder if there is a chance that not only 5.0 but 4.2 and above also have it. I don't care to support anything before that.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out. Install 4.2 in the simulator, and see whether your app runs.

Comment: From my experience with simulators I have observed (and still do) that they do not actually have any support for geo related functionality at all so I feel like a simulator won't get me anywhere. For example the latest CLGeocoder from apple showed no meaningful results at all on any simulator (5.x or 4.x) before I posted this question. Also since it didn't outright crash, I can't say that it is jsut not supported either. Therefore, notice the: "Does anyone have an answer via their first hand experience with an iPhone" part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)geoCodeLocation:(id)sender{
    [self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
         //String to hold address
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
         NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name 
         NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name 
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

         NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);
          //Print the location to console
         NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

         //Set the label text to current location
         [locationLabel setText:locatedAt];

     }];
For more see property of CLPlacemark Link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html (Support in iOS 5.0 because in previous MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated)
```